# Homotopy limit of a cosimplicial category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories, simplicial-categories

Consider the usual model structure on Cat (category of small categories).
Which are the fibrations of the injective model structure on the category of cosimplicial categories $Fun( \Delta ,Cat )$?

Actually, I wonder how can I compute homotopy limits of cosimplicial categories (considering them as diagrams in Cat)...

Edit: I'm most interested in understanding how to compute the homotopy limit of a cosimplicial diagram in $Cat$

Thank you in advance

Comment: I doubt that taking Cat as a target category may simplify the characterization of fibrations in the injective model structure on cosimplicial diagrams. I'd say you should proceed as in the general case.

Comment: @Fernando Muro, Thank you (again) for your comment. Actually, I'm more interested in understanding how to compute homotopy limits of cosimplicial diagrams in $Cat$. Do you know if there is an easy way to do so?
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know of any specific way of computing such homotopy limits in Cat. I would proceed as in a general (simplicial?) model category.

Comment: Consider the full subcategory  $ \Delta _n = \left\{ 0, \ldots , n\right\} $ of $\Delta $.
Computing the homotopy limit of diagram $ \Delta _n \to Cat $ is the same as computing the homotopy limit of its right Kan extension $ \Delta \to Cat $.
My guess, however, is that, for $ n=2 $, the reciprocal holds. I mean compunting the homotopy limit of a diagram $ \Delta \to Cat $ would be the same as computing the homotopy limit of its restriction $ \Delta _ 2\to Cat $. But I could not prove yet (since I don't have clue of what are the fibrant objects of $Fun (\Delta , Cat) $).

Comment: The standard model structure on $\mathbf{Cat}$ is indeed simplicial, provided one uses as the nerve of the maximal _subgroupoid_ of $[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}]$ as the simplicial hom-space $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})$: see [this note](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/cat-ho.dvi) of Rezk. Thus one can use the standard technique of bar and cobar constructions: see e.g. [this preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610194) of Shulman). Note that the existence of injective/projective model structures is not needed.

Comment: Maybe section 6.5 in http://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/hocolim.pdf can help. In general, this paper is a very nice account on hocolim (just dualize for holim).

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "compute"?

Comment: @JonBeardsley , I would like to know if there is an simplified algorithm to compute the homotopy limit of a given diagram $ \Delta \to Cat $, as there is for pushouts in the general setting (with the cofibration replacement) or as there is for $ \Delta\to Set $ (trivial).
But, I would be satisfied if I could answer the "implicit question" of my comment above.

Comment: Id est, I would like to prove (or disprove) my guess above.

Comment: Lemma 3.4.11 in [_Sketches of an elephant_, Part B] shows that a certain non-full subcategory of $\mathbf{\Delta}$ is 2-coinitial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer the title question about computing homotopy limits. Let $A : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ be a small (strict) diagram. By expanding the definitions of the cobar construction, one eventually discovers that $\operatorname{holim} A$ can be computed as the end
$$\int_{[n] : \mathbf{\Delta}} \left[ \mathbf{I} [n], \prod_{(c_0, \ldots, c_n)} \mathcal{C} (c_n, c_{n-1}) \times \cdots \times \mathcal{C} (c_1, c_0), A c_0 \right]$$
where $\mathbf{I} [n]$ is the contractible groupoid with $n + 1$ objects. In more familiar terms, this is just the hom-category of all morphisms between a certain pair of cosimplicial categories.

Here is a description of an object in $\operatorname{holim} A$:

- For each object $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have an object $a_c$ in $A c$.
- For each morphism $f : c_1 \to c_0$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have an isomorphism $\mu_f : f (a_{c_1}) \to a_{c_0}$ in $A c_0$; and $\mu_{\mathrm{id}_c} = \mathrm{id}_{a_c}$ for all objects $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$.
- For each composable pair $f_1 : c_2 \to c_1, f_0 : c_1 \to c_0$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have a commutative triangle in $A c_0$,
  $$\begin{array}{ccc}
  f_0 (f_1 (a_{c_2})) & \rightarrow & f_0 (a_{c_1}) \\
  & \searrow & \downarrow \\
  && a_{c_0}
  \end{array}$$
  i.e. $\mu_{f_0 \circ f_1} = \mu_{f_0} \circ f_0 (\mu_{f_1})$.
- For each composable triple in $\mathcal{C}$, we have a commutative tetrahedron in $A c_0$.
- etc.

In fact, the coherence conditions above degree 2 are automatic if all the triangles commute. Thus we see that an object in $\operatorname{holim} A$ is the same thing as a pseudocone over $A$ (where we regard $A$ as a pseudofunctor with the canonical coherence data). Unsurprisingly, the morphisms are the same, so $\operatorname{holim} A$ (as constructed above) is the pseudolimit of $A$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me a lot. So, your conclusion was that the homotopy limit is the same concept of the pseudolimit of a strict diagram. I would like to ask, nevertheless, if there is a "end" formula like that of cobar construction for computing pseudolimits of pseudolimit of a "pseudodiagram" (non-strict diagram).

Comment: I do not know of such a formula. But there should be no real difference other than inserting coherence isomorphisms in the appropriate places.

Comment: What is this notation inside the end, which consists of square brackets with two commas inside? $[ , , ]$?